# Proxy address not working in react-native client

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to make a GET API request in my first react-native app(expo project, running it on my physical android device).
I'm seeing trouble while trying to make a get request using Axios - I have my backend in express connecting to Firebase DB.
{The below setup works fine in react web app}

```
  ... 
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    const userData = {
      email: email,
      password: password
    };
    axios.get('/alltests')
      .then((res) => {
        alert("Successfully loggedin", res)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data))
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("\n\nI'm in error block - frontend")
        console.log(err)
        alert(err);
        //setErrors(err.response.data)
      })
     ...
```

My package.json looks like ->

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.8.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "expo": "~36.0.0",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "https://asia-something.net/api"
}
```

However, if I use 
axios.get('https://asia-something.net/api/alltests')
this seems to be working in the code.

I'm not using localhost or running the backend on local server.
Can someone help me here, please?